# Why can't I call a function here?

Tags: python

Hi guys I was working on a shoppinglist-creator code but at the end I faced with a surprise.

My code:

```
import time
import math
import random
dict_of_lists={}
def addlist():
  while True:
    try:
      listname=str(raw_input("=>Name of the list:\n"))

      dict_of_lists[listname]={}
      break
    except ValueError:
      print "=>Please enter a valid name.\n"

  print "=>You added a new list named %s.\n" % (listname)
def printlists():
  for lists in dict_of_lists:
    return "-"+lists
def addproduct():
  while True:
    try:
      reachlistname=input("=>Name of the list you want to add a product,Available lists are these:\n %s \nPlease enter one:\n" % (printlists()))
      break
    except ValueError:
      print "=>Please enter a valid list name.\n"
  while True:
    try:
      productname=raw_input("=>Name of the product:\n")
      break
    except ValueError:
      print "=>Please enter a valid name.\n"
  while True:
    try:
      productprice=input("=>Price of the product:\n")
      if isinstance(float(productprice),float):
        break
    except ValueError:
          print "=>Please enter a valid number.\n"
  while True:
    try:
      productcount=input("=>Amount of the product:\n")
      if isinstance(int(productcount),int):
        break
    except ValueError:
      print "=>Please enter a valid number.\n"
  dict_of_lists[reachlistname][productname]={"price":productprice,"count":productcount}
  dict_of_lists[reachlistname]={productname:{"price":productprice,"count":productcount}}
allevents="1-Add a list"+" 2-Add a product to a list"  
def eventtochoose():
  while True:
    try:
      event=raw_input("=>What would you like to do? Here are the all things you can do:\n %s\nPlease enter the number before the thing you want to do:" % (allevents))
      if  not isinstance(int(event),int):
        print "\n=>Please enter a number.\n"
      else:
        if event==1:
          addlist()
          break
        elif event==2:
          addproduct()
          break

    except ValueError:
      print "\n=>Please enter a valid input.\n "

while True:
  print "%s" % ("\n"*100)
  eventtochoose()
```

So, the problem is (I suggest you run the code) it says "=>What would you like to do? Here are the all things you can do:
 1-Add a list 2-Add a product to a list
Please enter the number before the thing you want to do:" and when i put an answer it simply doesn't call the fucntion.

If I put 1 It should have called the fucntion addlist but I think it doesn't. There is nothing to explain I think just look at the code and find the problem if you want to help crocodiles. Thx

Comment: (a) This doesn't make any sense: `not isinstance(int(event),int)` -- it won't work as you expect, isn't really testing for anything, and won't catch the error you seem to want it to, (b) `event` is a string and these sort of equality tests `if event==1` will never be true.

Comment: Omg, I'm so dumb XD. I should put an int() tag right behind raw_input or use a normal input. I wonder how couldn't I see that. Thx

Comment: Yeah it works with one more little tweak. I made reachlistname equals to a variable. It should be a string. Now it works.

Comment: You could wrap the `raw_input` with an `int` call, but that'll throw an exception if the user entered a string that can't be converted (which is fine, I guess, if you catch it).

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting your input to an integer before comparing, so the comparisons are always false:

```
'1' == 1 # false
```

Try:

```
event = raw_input("=>What would you like to do? Here are the all things you can do:\n %s\nPlease enter the number before the thing you want to do:" % (allevents))
try:
    event = int(event)
    if event == 1:
        addlist()
    elif event == 2:
        addproduct()
        break
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a valid input')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `int(event)`, that returns an `int` if possible, and raises a `ValueError` if not. So, testing the type of the result doesn't do you any good—if your code gets that far, the type has to be an `int`.

You already have code to handle the `ValueError`, so you don't need any other test for the same problem.

Meanwhile, you want to start the number that you got from `int(event)`. That's the thing that can be `== 1`; the original string `'1'` will never be `== 1`.

So:

```
while True:
    try:
      event=raw_input("=>What would you like to do? Here are the all things you can do:\n %s\nPlease enter the number before the thing you want to do:" % (allevents))
      event = int(event)
      if event==1:
        addlist()
        break
      elif event==2:
        addproduct()
        break

    except ValueError:
      print "\n=>Please enter a valid input.\n "
```